# Soft memory exceeded raises critical error and return status 500

Tags: google-app-engine

I found a lot of posts in which people say's that when memory is exceeded instance should complete serving the request. In my application the instance is immediately shuted down.

Is the proper way? I can't find any informations about that in Google App Engine Developers so maybe someone could tell something about that. Maybe some article about that or something similar?

My app is served on GAE 1.9.4

[image: Screenshot of my log]

Comment: In theory it should complete, however in trying to complete if it hits the hard memory limit it will be stopped immediately.  There isn't a lot more to add given the lack of information you have provided. You haven't said what language your using, framework, how quickly you reach your memory limit, what it is your trying to do etc.. which is all information that will allow accurate advice on how you might proceed.

Comment: In screenshot which I add to the post is written that instance exceeded soft memory not hard. I'm using python with webapp2. I'm trying to send data to BQ using task queue. My handler receive small amount of data, pack that data to Google Cloud Storage then create new task which should read that data from GCS and then create an api call to BQ to load that data - in shortcut. To that handler is sended something around 800 small packs of data - it's query result from MSSQL database.

Comment: Ultimately you have no control, if google decides to kill your instance then it will. You don't provide any more info, so all I can say is fix the memory issue, which is better than getting hung up on why the instance was killed when you only got a soft memory limit.  Also your snapshot is not visible.

Comment: I edit my previous comment and repair screenshot link.

Comment: You screen shot shows two messages. The first telling you, that you have exceeded the softmeory limit. The second telling you the instance was terminated.  Are you using F1 instance ?  If so I don't see anything unexpected in the messages.

Comment: No, im using F2 instance class. Unexpected is that in many posts i found that request should be executed to the end properly not immediately killed [link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1837). I try to find any posible way to handle that data loading. I can't lose any of those packages and i can't do anything when that critical error occurs. Maybe is some way to kill instances which almost exceed memory or something like this?

Comment: I would profile you app on dev using apptrace and see where your memory is being consumed.

Comment: I don't know if you can see that my app served 32 requests. Because of  that profiling handler on dev server didn't tell me what i should do with instance which exceeds memory